# Recovery tool Installer - Packages Offline

Tags: 8.1, windows-10, recovery-tool

Is there a Windows Phone Recovery tool packages available Offline?

I am using a Lumia 520 and 1520. I have installed Windows phone 10 10149 build in both phones and my 520 is dead slow and I could not go to the Phone App to call any one. So, I decided to revert my 520 to Windows phone 8.1 OS and installed Windows Phone Recovery tool.

But the packages are not getting downloaded in the Windows Phone Recovery tool. It keeps on saying "Error and Please try again". I have a stable internet connection and I have disabled Firewall and yet couldn't download the packages.

So, Could someone tell me if there is any Offline package available for Windows Phone 8.1 OS to be fed to the Windows Phone Recovery tool to start with?

Comment: Witch version of Recovery tools are you using?

Comment: @Vitor Canova: 2.1.1

Comment: I thought it would be [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/lumia-520521devices-unusable-after-using-windows/c5d072d5-c26e-4a02-907d-fde2ca5e34c7) but the version was 1.2.4

Comment: @Vitor Canova: The Microsoft answer link you talks about recovering the Lumia 520/521 phone which got unusable after using WPRT. But my question, I am not able to download the packages for Lumia 520 from WPRT.

Comment: Why do you are so sure packages are not downloaded? The Message you provided (the one the SW provided) is very broad.

Comment: Because I could see that it has downloaded few % of the full progress and also I have checked the location - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages where the packages would download and I could not see any file.

Comment: How is your network? Are you connected with a regular Home configuration (I mean, DSL access point...) or in an enterprise with firewalls/proxy?

Comment: I have a stable home configured network. I now have downloaded the new Windows Device recovery tool and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You download your [Lumia 520 mobile firmware](http://lumiafirmware.com/) according to your mobile *manufacturer name* which is in *Setting -> Extras -> Extras & info*.

*Download **only** **.ffu** file According to your device.*

Then download the **[Windows Device Recovery Tool](https://repairavoidance.blob.core.windows.net/packages/WindowsDeviceRecoveryToolInstaller.exe)**, install it on your PC and then follow the below given instructions.

1. Now open CMD as administrator
2. Type the following

   **64-bit PC:** `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Care Suite\Windows Device Recovery Tool`

   **32-bit PC:** `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Care Suite\Windows Device Recovery Tool`
3. Connect now your phone to your PC
4. Type in cmd `thor2 -mode uefiflash -ffufile "C:\the location of the ffu\file name.ffu" -do_full_nvi_update -do_factory_reset`
5. Wait now until your phone gives a green screen
6. Type now in cmd `thor2 -mode rnd -bootnormalmode`

Comment: I got an error code in the 6th command `0x14821`.